# Managing dynamic add and remove element with textarea tinymce plugin

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, tinymce, textarea

Could anyone help me, I am trying to use `tinymce` in all my textarea

basically I have `add button` that would copy the `div` and all its element

also I have `delete button` once user want to delete the div generated.

that two button works fine..

my problem is tinymce doesn't work in the newly add element, I have read that tinymce wont work on the same `id's`, `id's` must be unique, but I cant figure out how to do it.

concerns:
 1. is same `id` cause conflict here?
 2. If not how could I fixed this?

so far this is all I have [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kodewrecker/gWZhM/2/)

** the newly created textarea doesn't work **

any suggestion,comments,instruction is well appreciated.. thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by "** the newly created textarea doesn't work **"? if i push the button "add another image" there is a new editor

Comment: yeah. try to write something on new texteditor it wont work :(

Answer (score 0):

Problem here is you cannot clone a DOM element structure containing the DOM elements of the first editor. Plus the newly created elements have the same editor id.

You should use jQuery to generate new DOM elements similar to those with class `clonedInput` and take care you assign another id than "ta"

Comment: I see. I just thought that upon cloning you may rename id's or name's.something like that!

Comment: but you cloned the node with all the nodes created by tinymce!